How to ping self via the gateway?
Trying to check connection, pinging self via the gateway. The problem is that the kernel does not send packet to the outside world (tracking them with tcpdump). How can I bypass routing mechanisms?
Gateway has disabled ICMP responses. ARP ping requests are unavailable due to PPP connection.

You can try to deactivate the loopback interface 'sudo ip link set lo down'. Then The packets should be sent out to your router and it may or may not decide to send them back, depending on its configuration. Dont forget 'sudo ip link set lo up'. afterwards.

will only work if your router supports NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning

@jjj, thank you for suggestion! Tested on two machines, first via WLAN, second via PPP – not working, just hangs after running self ping :( Maybe because of the lack of support for the NAT feature, as DavidPostill noted, but tcpdump is also silent.

Trying to check connection While I have written an answer as a proof of concept, it may not actually make sense for you to use it. For example, a router could have interface-based firewall rules that allows only LAN-to-WAN and WAN-to-LAN communication, so the host may be able to talk to the WAN / Internet even if the "check" "failed". Or, the router might forbids only LAN-to-WAN traffics, in that case the "check" may "succeed", and yet the host will still not be able to talk to the WAN / Internet. So the question is, what exactly are you trying to check? Why don't you just ping the gateway?

@TomYan, yes, there are may be some firewall restrictions. I'm trying to check modem connection (accordingly, working with PPP) in the closed network. Since the mobile operator's gateway does not respond to ICMP requests and there is no guarantee, that any other hosts in the network will be available, thus, the idea to ping self appeared. But also found an another method to verify connection – LCP Echo, it may be more relevant, will try it too

To get the packet that destined at (one of) the host's own IP address(es) out to respective gateway, you'll need to do the following:

Delete the corresponding local route from the local table; this stops the host from considering the destination as itself; a route in the main table (assuming there is no interfering ip rule) will be used then.

Add the same local route to an alternative route table and add an ip rule with the condition of not iif lo for the table; this will make the host consider the traffics destined at itself when they are looped back by/from the gateway. (Also, without this the host will not answer the ARP request from the gateway, I think.)

Add an indirect route for the IP address (to the main table; with the gateway's IP address as the nexthop); this stops the host from trying to resolve the IP address through ARP and but send the traffics to the gateway. (Therefore this should not be necessary if the link in concern is a point-to-point link.)


Let's say the pinging host's IP is 192.168.181.43 and the gateway's IP adddress is 192.168.181.1:
sudo ip route del local 192.168.181.43
sudo ip route add local 192.168.181.43 dev host0 table 123
sudo ip rule add not iif lo lookup 123
sudo ip route add 192.168.181.43 via 192.168.181.1

When you delete a local route (i.e., the first command) without specify which table to delete from, it will work on the local table.
The table number (123) in the second command is arbitrary. You may use any number you like. (I don't remember if there's any reserved / special number, but I suppose you'd at least be fine as long as it's within the range between 10 and 60000.) Just make sure you use the same number as the argument for lookup in the third command.
To state the obvious, host0 in the second command is the network interface that 192.168.181.43 is configured on.
not iif lo in the third command means that only the traffics received from another host would be affected by this rule. There will be two "copies" of every packet -- the one sent to the gateway, and the other one received from the gateway, and only the latter should be "routed by" the local route in table 123. (Note that "every packet" refers to both the cases of ICMP Echo Request and ICMP Echo Reply, that is, "two copies" does NOT mean "a request and reply pair", but two request / reply copies.)
The fourth command works on the main table.

If you run ip rule, you will see that the rule that looks up the local table has the lowest priority 0 (i.e., highest precedence). This is why (by default; as the kernel automatically adds local routes for addresses configured on a host to the table) traffics that destined at a host's own IP addresses would not egress the host but get looped back to itself.
You will also see that the new ip rule added with the third command have priority just lower (hence precedence just higher) than the one that looks up the main table (if nothing else has added an ip rule).

While whether this could work probably depends on the firewall on the router, I don't think it requires support for NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning. (Although I admit that I don't know the definition of that very well.) At the very least, when I test with a Linux router that "masquerade" for any traffics with source IP that is within the LAN IP subnet (192.168.181.0/24), the NAT does not stop it from working (which makes sense to me anyway). It also works if the NAT is disabled.

For the record, if it works for you, you'd probably see something like:
Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.181.43)

in the ping output. In some cases this would stop the pinging host from sending the ping to the gateway but the "ultimate" destination, but in this case it doesn't / can't really make a difference. Also, in the case of a Linux router, you can stop it from sending ICMP Redirect Message by setting the send_redirects sysctl of the corresponding interface to 0.

Great answer with detailed explanation, thank you! Tried in 3 cases: home Wi-Fi router, Android Wi-Fi AP and OpenVPN connection. 1 and 2 didn't work (because of firewall rules, maybe), but I see some outgoing packets with tcpdump -i wlp1s0. 3 worked like a charm. Will perform more experiments later
